# Send commands to another terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I have this setup where I have computer with ssh and a display where I have a user logged in to terminal. What I want to do is send commands like I was using that local session with keyboard. I tried to echo to /dev/tty1 but it just shows what I typed instead executing it. Which makes sense. The system only has bash so no GUI or anything like that.

Comment: Do you really need to send commands to that session, or would executing them in an independent session (i.e. `ssh remotehost "some command; another command; yet another command"`) be sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [TIOCSTI ioctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614264/unable-to-fake-terminal-input-with-termios-tiocsti#29615101) can inject characters into a terminal, or see instead [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) on Linux to generate keyboard (or mouse!) input.

- [`ttywrite.c`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/tty/ttywrite.c) - sample C implementation
- [`Term::TtyWrite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::TtyWrite) - Perl implementation

  ```
  $ sudo perl -MTerm::TtyWrite \
    -e 'Term::TtyWrite->new("/dev/pts/2")->write("echo hi\n")'
  ```

Comment: This Q&A is Linux-specific, fortunately.  Note that other operating systems started to drop TIOCSTI a year after this answer was written.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406690/5132