# How to write to terminal device stdin of running process from a different terminal without any prior preparation?

Tags: linux, terminal, pts

There seem to be plenty of similar questions, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process

However the answer given is to prepare the program beforehand by making its stdin a pipe.

There's also:

https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi

Which is answered by commanding a terminal multiplexer under which the program in question is running. That means it also needs prior preparation.

This question is about how to do this *without* having done any preparation beforehand.

At first I thought it might be as simple as:

```
echo foo > /proc/$p/fd/0
```

but that just writes to the terminal. So then I tried:

```
echo foo > /proc/$terminal_emulator/fd/$ptmx_fd
```

but that also fails because it just opens up a new terminal device slave for echo.

I already have an answer using `gdb` (*sigh*) which I'll be posting below, but I wonder if anyone knows of a simpler and better alternative.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306806/send-commands-to-another-terminal

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That answer works. I'm not sure what to suggest here. Should this be marked as a duplicate of that, or would you make an answer that references and/or quotes that answer?

Comment: TIOCSTI only works as root or on the controlling tty. And writing stuff into the master side of the tty only works when  it's a pseudo-tty, and you can attach to the process holding the master fd -- in the case of a ssh session, that would be a process running as root. Anyways, for yet another TIOCSTI sample, you can also look  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493684/308316).

Comment: If you're satisfied that one of the other questions/answers qualifies as a duplicate, you can click on `close` just below your question, then `Duplicate of`, then paste the URL of the duplicate question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JoL You can accept the duplicate which is easier than 5 reviewers agreeing: *Yes this is the perfect duplicate...*

Comment: @Fabby I hadn't noticed I could do that. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: We live and we learn...  **;-)** Thank you!  **0:-)**

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

pid="$1"
stdin_data="$2"

for p in $(pstree -sp "$pid" | grep -Po '(?<=\()\d+(?=\))' | tac); do
  [[ -r "/proc/$p/fd" ]] || continue
  for f in /proc/$p/fd/*; do
    if [[ "$(readlink "$f")" = /dev/ptmx ]]; then
      fd="$(basename "$f")"
      break 2
    fi
  done
done

sudo gdb -p "$p" --batch -x =(printf '%s' '            
  p (int)write($fd, "$stdin_data", (int)strlen("$stdin_data"))
')
```

I don't like that the script argument can be a C injection.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't, writing to a process' stdin file doesn't make the process read what you appended. See this answer for a full explanation: https://serverfault.com/a/962956